# How can I change a double in binary defined by String to many single bits?

Tags: java, binary, double

For example, If I have a double,

```
double x = 123.567
```

and I turn it to binary form, like

```
String y = Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToLongBits(x))
```

Now, I stuck in how to get each single bits from this binary(String y). Or Can I get those single bit from `double x` directly. Because String can not use logic and, I can't figure any idea about this.

Comment: '`String` can not use logic' Who told you that? Because they're wrong.

Comment: You're on the right track with `doubleToLongBits`. You could inspect the characters of your string using `String.charAt(int)` or `String.toCharArray()`, or you could directly inspect the bits in the long using this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092411/java-checking-if-a-bit-is-0-or-1-in-a-long

Comment: So you mean that is worked ? y & 0x1?

Comment: you can look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095463/how-to-convert-a-byte-into-bits) which provides multiple different solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the purpose of your approach is, but maybe you should have a look at [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)? You could put your longs into an array, create a BitSet using valueOf and then use a data structure that's actually meant to be used for logical operations.

Comment: Caveat: `BitSet.valueOf` uses little-endian byte ordering.